# cursor.getLong() returns wrong value

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a column in the table with a value = 273655946872653540. But when I do cursor.getLong(0), it returns me 273655946872653537.

It seems like it is getting roundoff. Is it because value is too large? Still it is less then 2^63-1.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What is type that column?

Comment: Column type is INTEGER

Comment: I suspect that the value gets converted to a double in the process, for reasons not yet specified in the question. `273655946872653540L` is `2.73655946872653536E17` as `double` (which is still off-by-one from the value you included in the question).

Comment: I am still not getting how should it get converted to a double. I am doing long id = cursor.getLong(0);

Comment: How do you know there's the value `273655946872653540` - how you're storing it there?

Comment: When I checked in the database(by backing up the database file into SD Card and viewing it in the FireFox_plugin-SQLite Manager) I came to know that value is 273655946872653540

But when I debug my app and inspect the value of a variable it was 273655946872653537

Comment: Ok - could you add some code that shows the table schema (`CREATE TABLE`) and how you are retrieving/displaying that particular value.